# Create model when processing form with class based view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to learn class based view in django 1.7.

I have two models, second model has foreign key to first.

```
class A(models.Model):                    
    text = models.CharFeild(max_length=10)

class B(models.Model):
    a1 = models.ForeignKey(A)
    content = models.TextField()

class BCreateView(CreateView):
    model = B
    fields = ['a1', 'content']
```

and form:

```
<form action="?" method="post">
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="create" /> 
</form>
```

When user input data into form instead of dropdown list with values from first models I want to use text input, so user can just type text into and instance for A create before processing form for B. And I can't figure out how to do that with class based views and forms.

Comment: May be I have to override method is_valid in Form class, but how can I change data in widget?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom form, instead of relying on the auto generated form django gives you with CreateView.

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = B
    fields = ('a1', 'content)
    widgets = {
        'a1': TextInput(),
    }
```

And then in your View:

```
class BCreateView(CreateView):

    model = B
    form_class = MyForm
```

See more details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: Even if I'l create such form I still need custom validation method, because A should be created before B can be saved. Here a1 takes only pk, but I need pass just text.

Answer (score 0):

So eventually I inherited BCreateView from FormView and define form class as descendant of forms.Form and check form in post method manually.